# Measurement Studio controls not visible in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, controls, measurement-studio

I am trying to get started with the NI Measurement Studio.  After intalling the software, the controls don't show up in my Toolbox.  I get the text "Controls in this category are unavailable for the .Net Framework 4 Client Profile.  To change this setting, open the Project Propeties window."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newbie mistake -- I just changed the Profile to .Net Framework 4 and it works.  It just didn't like the .Net Framework 4 Client Profile.